# How to define operator class for composite type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, composite-types, range-types, gist-index

I have a composite type. And I want to define exclusion constraint on it, that would also be combined with range exclusions, but getting the following error.

---

```
create type example_t as (
    x uuid,
    y text
);

create table example (
    id example_t not null,
    time tstzrange not null,

    exclude using gist (id with =, time with &&)
);
```

---

```
ERROR: data type example_t has no default operator class for access method "gist" HINT: You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type. SQL state: 42704
```

How can I define the operator class for 'example_t' composite type?

Answer (score 2):

It is complicated to define a new GiST operator class. You'd have to define [support functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-GIST-SUPPORT-TABLE) and matching strategies. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-extensibility.html) for an example how that is done using C functions.

But I think it would be much simpler not to include the column of type `example_t` in the exclusion constraint, but the individual elements `id.x` and `id.y`. That way you can probably get along with the operator classes defined in the [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) contrib module.

Comment: Yes, it's probably the simplest I might do.

Comment: I've just hoped that where is a way to reuse operators of uuid and text classes to do so.